# Reload jQuery content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the jQuery slider library [pixedelic camera](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/). I chose this library, because it is free and very easy to use. Basically all you need to put in your code is:

```
    <div class="camera_wrap camera_azure_skin" id="camera_wrap_1">
                <div data-thumb="images/slides/thumbs/bridge.jpg" data-src="images/slides/bridge.jpg">
                 </div>
                 <div data-thumb="images/slides/thumbs/leaf.jpg" data-src="images/slides/leaf.jpg">
                 </div>
                 <div data-thumb="images/slides/thumbs/road.jpg" data-src="images/slides/road.jpg">
                 </div>
    </div>

+ some include scripts
```

I want to let user to add image dynamically, without page refresh. Thanks to simplicity of input source I thought, that it will be very easy -> just append new div to slideshow.

```
$('#some_button').click(function(){
    $('#camera_wrap_1').append('<div data-thumb="images/slides/thumbs/road.jpg" data-src="images/slides/rabbit.jpg"></div>');
})
```

But the problem is that this slideshow is generated "onload" of the page, and is rewriting this simple input in to more complex structure. That means, that this simple append will not work, because is added on the run. Is there any chance, how to use jQuery, Ajax or anything to refresh div #tendiv to force jquery to generate new content?

Comment: have you tried rerunning $('#camera_wrap_1').camera(); after the append?

Comment: The library might need to search for the elements to manipulate in a different way:  Instead of `$('.someclass')` it'd need to be `$('body').find('.someclass')` - this allows JQuery to look at the HTML that's currently on the page, including dynamically added content.

If it's open source, I'd try editing their file to do that - but I know sometimes that can be a tall order.

Comment: this is ugly, but should work: save the innerHTML of #camera_wrap_1, concat more data-thumb div strings to that, then .html(concated).camera(). basically, start from scratch each time. simpler than forking...

Answer (score 0):

You can try remove the old div id = 'camera_wrap_1' , and then add the new one named 'camera_wrap_2', then use the  $('#camera_wrap_2').camera();. like this method , remove before one ,add new one, but the id increase. It may be work.